# Jekyll clear build folder with Gulp

Tags: gulp, jekyll

I'm using a build environment with Jekyll + Gulp. So, using the `gulpfile.js` below, the build process generate first a `dist/css` folder with the compiled css inside, and then clear the entire `dist` folder for put the `jekyll build` result inside. So, i'm not able to compile the scss files inside the `dist` folder because every time jekyll it completely clear it.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var child       = require('child_process');


gulp.task('jekyll', function (done) {
    return child.spawn('jekyll' , ['build']).on('close', done);
});

gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'jekyll'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/_sass/theme.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['scss'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/_sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['src/*.html', 'src/_layouts/*.html', 'src/_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Jekyll can compile sass natively, why using gulp for this?

Comment: I'm not using it only for sass

Answer (score 0):

I have to avoid running `jekyll` task in parallel with `styles` and `scripts` so I have used a `runSequence`.

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
    runSequence('jekyll', ['styles', 'scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Jekyll config you need to declare which folders you want to keep:

```
keep_files: [ css, build ]
```

> When clobbering the site destination, keep the selected files. Useful for files that are not generated by jekyll; e.g. files or assets that are generated by your build tool. The paths are relative to the destination.

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/